# função map() com .format

Tags: python, funções, map

estou começando a programação em python e fiquei em dúvida com uma expressão que me deparei.

ao construir um dataframe a seguinte função foi utilizada para um dos valores atribuídos : *summary_calculations["Preço Médio"].map("${:,.2f}".format)*

gostaria de entender essa parte: ${:,.2f}".format

segue código do dataframe inteiro :

```
 summary_calculations = summary_calculations.round(2)
summary_calculations ["Preço Médio"] = summary_calculations["Preço Médio"].map("${:,.2f}".format)
summary_calculations ["Total de Vendas"] = summary_calculations["Total de Vendas"].map("${:,.2f}".format)
summary_calculations = summary_calculations.loc[:, ["Número de Itens Únicos", "Preço Médio", "Número de Compras", "Total de Vendas"]]
```

Desde já, agradeço

Answer (score 0):

o `"${;.2f}".format` está basicamente formatando o valor do seu dataframe
para o padrao : `$valor.decimal`

Pegando o exemplo abaixo eu estou formatando todos os valores  com a string customizada adicionando uma frase antes do seu valor original como alterando um campo de float para string com o formato personalizado.

vale da  uma olhada na documentação de cada metodo para ver oque é possível fazer

1. [Documentação .format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-format-spec)
2. [Documentação .map Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', None, 'rabbit'])
s.map('I am a {}'.format)

#OUTPUT
#0       I am a cat
#1       I am a dog
#2      I am a None
#3    I am a rabbit
#dtype: object

metricas =pd.Series([10.2,20.1])
metricas.map("${:.2f}".format)
#OUTPUT
#0    $10.20
#1    $20.10
#dtype: object
```